# What is the flaw in the logic

Tags: c, pointers

I am currently learning about pointers and array in C. The following questions has been really bugging me for days. Please clarify.

Suppose I declare an integer array like this:

```
int a[]={1,2,3,4,5}
```

We know that the base address of the array is the pointer to the first element of the array. So if we try to execute the command:

```
printf("%u ",a);
```

The base address i.e. the address of `1` will be printed. Now if we try to execute the following statement:

```
printf("%u",&a);
```

Then won't `&a` will be a pointer to a pointer and should print the address of the variable which contains the address of the base element of the integer array? Instead what I get is the same value of `a` and `&a`.

Where is the flaw? Please explain it.

Comment: Technically you should be casting all those pointers to `void *` when passing them to `printf()`.

Comment: ... and use the format specifier `%p` instead of `%u`.

Answer (score 0):

**Arrays are not pointers:**

---

- `int arr[10]`:

  - Amount of memory used is `sizeof(int)*10` bytes
  - The values of `arr` and `&arr` are necessarily identical
  - `arr` points to a valid memory address, but cannot be set to point to another memory address

---

- `int* ptr = malloc(sizeof(int)*10)`:

  - Amount of memory used is `sizeof(int*) + sizeof(int)*10` bytes
  - The values of `ptr` and `&ptr` are not necessarily identical (in fact, they are mostly different)
  - `ptr` can be set to point to both valid and invalid memory addresses, as many times as you will

Answer (score 0):

a is defined as an object of an array type

```
int a[]={1,2,3,4,5};
```

The size of the object calculated as sizeof( a ) is equal to 5 * sizeof( int ) and if the sizeof( int ) is equal to 4 then the size of the object is equal to 20.

Expression &a gives the address of the object.  Its type is `int ( * )[5]`. You could write

```
int ( *p )[5] = &a;
```

If you will increment p

```
++p;
```

then p will have value that is 20 bytes greater than the original value of p.

Type of expression a is `int *`.

From the C Standard

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary &
>   operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an
>   expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
>   expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial
>   element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object
>   has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

You can write

int *q = a;

If you will increment q

```
++q;
```

then q will have value that is 4 bytes (sizeof( int )) greater than the original value of q.

Both p and q address the same extent of memory. Only they address objects of different types and sizes.